# VScodeにてJavaの実行環境を作りたい(組み込みターミナル内でのjavaコマンド実行、自動フォーマット有効化)

Tags: java, linux, vscode

### 環境情報

ThinkpadX270 / alter linux
VScode 1.67.2
java -version

```
openjdk version "18.0.1.1" 2022-04-22
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 18.0.1.1+2)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 18.0.1.1+2, mixed mode)
```

### 達成したいこと

VScodeにて、以下を実現したいです
・予測変換、自動フォーマットの有効化
・VScode内ターミナルからの実行

### 症状

まず、VScode内ターミナルからの実行ができません。
java コマンドにて、printのみ実行するクラスの実行に失敗します。以下、ログ

```
sh: java: コマンドが見つかりません
```

加えて、jdkを入手するように、という旨のポップアップが上がります。

### 試したこと

1. 拡張機能の確認
   Java Extension Packはインストール済みを確認。再インストール済み。
2. 個別で立ち上げたターミナルからのテストprintクラス実行
   成功。
3. パスの確認
   個別で起動したターミナルと同じpathを見ているはずなのに、VScode内ターミナルからはjavaコマンドが実行されない。

以下は、VScode内のターミナルからの実行

```
sh-5.1$ which java
which: no java in (/app/bin:/app/bin:/app/bin:/usr/bin:/home/a7uku/.var/app/com.visualstudio.code/data/node_modules/bin)
```

以下は、個別に立ち上げたzsh内からの実行

```
 which java
/usr/bin/java
```

##コメントを受けてのアクション

1. /etc/shells の確認
   以下、ともに記載あり

```
/bin/zsh
/usr/bin/zsh
```

2.ターミナル（vscode統合ではない）からsh, bash起動、javaコマンド確認
sh, bashともに起動、javaコマンドテスト成功

### 質問者の原因予測

VScode内部として見ている実行ファイルが違うように見える。
エイリアスとしての/usr/bin/javaの参照に問題があるように見える。

Answer (score 0):

右上に現在使用している shell の名前が出ていますので `zsh` になっているかを確認してみてください。
おそらく `zsh` にはなっていないと思うので、 `+` アイコンの右のプルダウンメニューを開いて `zsh` を選択してください。

新しくターミナルが開きますので、そこで `java` コマンドを実行してみてください。 `.zshrc`(など `zsh` 固有の設定ファイル)で `PATH` 設定を行っているのであればコマンドは通るようになると思います。

問題なければ、同じプルダウンメニューの `Select Default Profile` から、デフォルトで起動する shell を `zsh` に変更します。

参考: [Integrated Terminal in Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/integrated-terminal)

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。おっしゃるとおり、使用中のシェルはshになっていました。ただ、プルダウンメニュー上にzshが出てきません。規定のプロファイル選択にもzshは不在です。shでzshコマンドを叩いてもコマンドが見つかりませんので、vscodeからzshが見れていないという予測で調査します。

Comment: VSCode は `/etc/shells` を見ているようですが、 `zsh` はこのファイルに登録されていますか？ / あるいは、本文に記載しているページの[Configuring profiles](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/integrated-terminal#_configuring-profiles)節に、 `settings.json` ファイルへの手動設定方法も書かれています。 / [flatpack でインストールすると不具合がある](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/146981)といった報告もあるようなので、どうやってインストールしたのか、というのも必要な情報かもしれません。(また、 `zsh` のインストール方法も関わっているかもしれません)

Comment: /etc/shells には、/bin/zsh, /usr/bin/zshともに登録されています。
settings.jsonへの設定を試行中です。
vscodeのインストールは記憶が怪しいのですが、yay -S visual-studio-code-binでインストールしていた可能性があります。
$FLATPAK_IDは空でした。よって、flatpackでのインストールではない想定です。